# copy folder from host to docker container using java ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, docker

i tried to copy folder from host to docker container using java ProcessBuilder, it exited with error code 1, but if i ran the same docker command from terminal , it worked.

my java code:

```
        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command("docker", "cp", "./cassandra/.", "cassandra:/cassandra/");

        try {
            Process process = processBuilder.start();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();   // <=== exitCode was 1
            assertThat(exitCode).as("copy cassandra folder from host to cassandra container").isZero();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assertions.fail("Failed to Initialize cassandra db", e);
        }
```

I can run the same command from terminal and it worked:

```
docker cp ./cassandra/. cassandra:/cassandra/
```

can anyone help?

Comment: try  processBuilder.command("docker cp  ./cassandra/. cassandra:/cassandra/"); instead

Comment: @satyesht That won't work and that's not how `ProcessBuilder` is meant to be used

Comment: It would be useful to call `inheritIO` on the `ProcessBuilder` before your execute the process, this way the error and output streams will be piped together, you may get an error message, assuming that `docker` generates one. According to the documentation `Exit Code 1 - Application error` - that's helpful

Comment: As MadProgrammer says or use `processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` to see the error message when you read stdout.